# My game freezes/crashes after back or menu button is pressed

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I am working on an android game and I am having a strange problem here. Every time I press back/menu/task button and i try to return in game, game freezes (Not responding(Wait/Close)). I even added onPause, onResume, onStop functions but the problem is still there.
There may be a problem with my code this is my MainActivitiy.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
    Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    String a = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    GamePlayScene.filePath = a;
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
```

And this is my MainThread

```
public class MainThread extends Thread{
public static final int MAX_FPS = 30;
private double avarageFPS;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private GamePanel gamePanel;
private boolean running;
public static Canvas canvas;

public void setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running = running;
}
public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel){
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    long startTime;
    long timeMillis = 1000 / MAX_FPS;
    long waitTime;
    long frameCount = 0;
    long totalTime = 0;
    long targetTime = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

    while (running) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
        waitTime = targetTime = timeMillis;
        try {
            if (waitTime > 0) {
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        frameCount++;
        if (frameCount == MAX_FPS) {
            avarageFPS = 1000 / ((totalTime / frameCount) / 1000000);
            frameCount = 0;
            totalTime = 0;
            System.out.println(avarageFPS);
        }
    }
}
```

On game start I get this, but this doesn't cause any problem with game:

```
12-14 00:19:41.967 6778-6778/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 12-14 00:19:41.967 6778-6778/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384 12-14 00:19:41.971 6778-6778/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() 12-14 00:19:41.971 6778-6778/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
```

After I press any button and I return in game i get this:

```
12-14 00:26:17.174 12130-12163/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet W/System.err: at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:343) 12-14 00:26:17.174 12130-12163/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet W/System.err: at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468) 12-14 00:26:17.174 12130-12163/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet W/System.err: at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:334) 12-14 00:26:17.174 12130-12163/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet W/System.err: at com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:66) 12-14 00:26:17.174 12130-12163/com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet W/System.err: at com.apps.lazy.rainbowjet.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:43)
```

And this is GamePanel

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
private MainThread thread;

private SceneManager manager;
private boolean isRunning = true;

public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);


    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT = context;
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    manager = new SceneManager();
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    while(true){
        try{
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        retry = false;
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    manager.recieveTouch(event);
            return true;
        //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void update(){
manager.update();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    manager.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: the simple reason for this is you are doing lot of computation on main thread or you are leaking memory. see your logs and post them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you added `onPause`, `onResume`, and `onStop`, but everything you do is to call the `super` function, so basically the overrides are useless. In those functions, you'd have to call `super` and actually do something else.

Second, if the problem is with the back menu, you should probably handle it in the `onBackPressed` function.

Try this, in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MainThread myThread = getMainThread();
    myThread.setRunning(false);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

where `getMainThread()` retrieves the reference of your thread in the activity (wherever it is)

Comment: on this line MainThread myThread = getMainThread();    getMainThread(): method is not found, since MainThread is a class i cannot create getter in there since i cant return the class itself, btw its not only with back button , its with every button whenever i leave the game and try to return to it, it freezes or rarely crashes

Comment: Excuse me, `MainThread` is a class that you wrote? Where is it referenced? Is it declared somewhere in the activity? How do you start that thread? I suppose that is not the [Android's MainThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/MainThread.html)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but `getMainThread()` is a name I just made up. I suppose that in your activity, you have some method, or global variable, in order to get that MainThread instance.

Comment: and where is GamePanel? is it called by the Activity?